# Help block overlaps sub-top bar popup

Tags: bug, design

On Stack Overflow family sites improving a question (available if you’re not logged in) leads to overlapping the help block with sup-top bar popup, e.g. Jon Skeet on enSO:

> [image: enso]

Developers survey on ruSO:

> [image: ruso]